# Scene2d click event after touchable disabled

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Assume we have scene with next actors:

- WidgetGroup root;
- Button button.
  Where button is a child of root.

Now just look at next steps:

1. Touch down on button;
2. Set root touchable to disabled;
3. Touch up on button;
4. Button click event happens.

In my opinion, it looks pretty wrong. Of course TouchListener has cancel() method and we can just call it for button to fix it, but what if root consist of dozen of touchable actors...

So, did I miss something or what is a proper way to disable touch for whole group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2789

Probably the best solution now is to write utility method that cancels touch focus for whole group hierarchy. Like so:

```
public static void cancelTouchFocus(Stage stage, Actor actor) {
    stage.cancelTouchFocus(actor);

    if (actor instanceof Group) {
        SnapshotArray<Actor> children = ((Group)actor).getChildren();
        if (children.size > 0) {
            Object[] snapshot = children.begin();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.size; i++) {
                cancelTouchFocus(stage, (Actor)snapshot[i]);
            }
            children.end();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you could just call `Stage#cancelTouchFocus(Actor actor)` but in this case you may disrupt active touch cycle on some other actor outside of this specific group.

Check github issue mentioned above for other solutions and ideas.